# Bootstrap 4 - tabbing order accessibility when using order classes

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I have some issues using bootstrap order classes e.g. `order-2 order-md-1` in combination with tab order for accessibility purposes because I want that the tab flow follows the visual flow.

Look at the following markup:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 order-2 order-md-1">
        <a href="link.html"
           class="back-link">
            Back
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 order-1 order-md-2">
        <input type="button"
               class="btn btn-brand btn-sm-block"
               value="Continue"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Which produces following view in the browser:

**Current tab behavior**
[image: Current tab behavior]

In essence I want that the tab flow follows the visual flow which doesn't happen using the order classes only.

**Expected tab behavior**
[image: Expected tab behavior]

Technically it's possible on the one hand to use the `tabindex` attribute with positive numbers but know it's bad practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no "easy fix" for this.

Funny anecdote: Firefox once kept the tab order for items as they were ordered on screen but this was said to be a bug and changed in a later release.

[One article about it](https://www.useragentman.com/blog/2017/01/28/flex-layout-fail-fixing-firefox-keyboard-accessibility-with-the-css-order-property/) and the [bugreport for firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=812687)

There are two ways to change the order of tabbing:

**You can do this via JS:**

Loop through each element and set an appropriate tabindex for it depending on it's placement. Depending on your site this might be more or less complex.

**Or you do it via duplicate content**

You don't use order property of flexbox and simply use the hidden-sm (-md, ...) classes of bootstrap to always show your content in the order it should be tabbed through. This is the easier approach but it leads to having elements twice in the HTML.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. This summarizes all the options so far. But sad that it's not handable on native bootstrap level without duplicating markup.

Comment: tbf this doesn't have anything to do with bootstrap, this affects all flexbox layouts (I think it's even bigger problem with grid layouts). This is (as mentioned in the article) by design, the order of flexbox (and grid) shouldn't change the order of dom, so the tabindex also stays the same...

Comment: well that's true :)